# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'visdom' when importing visdom

Tags: python, pip, conda, visdom

When i'm trying to run the following from python console (pycharm)

```
import visdom
```

When I try to run:

```py
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
```

I get the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'visdom'`

I've tried to install it through pip (`pip install visdom`), pip3 (`pip3 install visdom`) and conda (all the following commands):

```
conda install -c conda-forge visdom

conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 visdom

conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 visdom)
```

None of the above commands produced an error.

I'm using a Mac if it matters.

Comment: Hi Tav, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add the output log of installing `visdom` into your question as a `code block`?

Comment: _None of the above commands produced an error._ The package was installed successfully for each of the Conda commands you tried? _ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'visdom'_ Please share the **entire** error message/traceback.

Answer (score 5):

Always include full traceback firstly in your question. With what i have encountered before, try the following

Upgrade pip,

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

They try,

```
python -m pip install visdom
```

Answer (score 0):

I’ve encountered the same issue. I made it by installing visdom0.2.1 while the default version is 0.2.2.

following commands:

```
pip uninstall visdom

pip install visdom==0.2.1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to install with pip:

## Install Python server and client from pip

## Requires Python 3

Comment: Pip does not require Python 3. Note that the question stated that they *already tried using pip*.